# How to I generate a traffic report in Google Analytics with small graphs of sessions, users, and pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, reporting

The traffic report below has only sessions, users and page views. I can't find any way to restrict a traffic report to just those 3 items.

The report seems to derive from Behavior > Overview. Although that default report shows 8 items. How do I modify that report so it look like the one below? Meaning, how do you get the mini graphs below the larger graph when creating a custom report?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the example?   It may be that it is old and Google has since added items to it.   It is also possible that somebody erased parts from the screenshot.     Why do you want the report without the extra info?   It doesn't usually hurt anything to have it there.

Comment: The report was from Dec 2016. Basically, I want to know how do get the mini graphs rather than just the table that usually appears there.

Comment: I get the small graphs on the behavior overview report:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZbPC.png  Just took that screenshot now with in Firefox.

Comment: Right...and those are not the same 3 boxes are shown in the OP. How do you edit the behavior overview report to look the same? Or, how do you add these mini graphs to a custom report? I haven't found a way to accomplish either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot appears to come from "Audience" -> "Overview" rather than from "Behavior" -> "Overview".   On the audience overview report I get the same three small graphs as in your screenshot (plus a few others):

[image]

Comment: In both of those reports, I have more mini graphs. How do I change which graphs are displayed?

Comment: You can't change which are displayed.

Comment: Ok. In custom reports, is it possible to get the mini graphs?

Comment: Not that I could​ find